# Access flash settings under content settings in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash

I have been looking to change `flash settings` under `contentSettings` to `allow automatically` using `JavaScript or chrome extensions`.

Here i found documentation for same :

> https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings

but, the problem is documentation is not showing any options related to flash settings .. Javascript, plugins, css are there.

so, is there any alternative using which i can access/modify the Flash settings under content settings.

[image]

Comment: Are you making a Chrome Extension? What does it do? Also there are **no** Flash _"settings to allow automatically using JavaScript or chrome extensions"_. You found the Settings page in your picture so what's the problem?

Comment: @VC.One yes.. I'm trying to make extension. If the extension is installed i will `auto enable flash settings` from `content settings`. Documentation has methods to manage all settings expect flash.

Comment: Flash Player is a **plugin** so I guess [**this section**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#property-plugins) should apply to it. I say _should_ only because browsers are trying to stop Flash content auto-running without User allowing it (this is now a per site policy in Chrome), in short User must first visit a site with Flash to get option of _"Allow Flash for this site"_.